# Javascript для 'a onclick'

Tags: javascript, html

На сайте есть такое:

```
<a class="sform" onclick="showForm();">Показать форму</a>
```

Как сделать javascript, который автоматически будет нажимать у элемента **a** **onclick**?

В Chrome, к примеру, для **input**:

```
<input type="submit" name="ct$Add" value="Принять" id="H1_Add" class="form1">
```

Сделал так:

```
 if(!alread_click)      
 {
    var button_element = document.getElementById('H1_Add');
    button_element.click();
    alread_click = true;
 }
```

А вот для **a onclick** не получается.

Comment: Проще всего - вот так: `showForm()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - действительно, просто вызвать метод `showForm`.
Или сделать так же, как вы сделали для `<input>`:

```js
function showForm () {
   var a = document.getElementById('show-form');
   a.innerHTML = "Форма показана"; 
   a.className = "form-shown";
}
  
function clickToShowForm() {
   var a = document.getElementById('show-form');
   a.click();
}
```

```css
.sform {
    background-color: green;
}

.form-shown {
    background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<a id="show-form" class="sform" onclick="showForm();">Показать форму</a>
<input style="display: block" type="button" onclick="clickToShowForm();" value="Нажать 'показать форму'"/>
```